# Is there a way to take control of an open Edge or Chrome browser window using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to use VBA to transfer data from an Excel sheet to a number of input boxes on a webpage.  Due to a couple of considerations specific to this site it would be much, much easier if I could simply log in to the webpage manually then use Selenium (or whatever) to take control of the browser window and execute the data entry tasks.  My impression is that this was quite doable with Internet Explorer, but that's been phased out, and it looks like there's not a very robust method for doing this with Google Chrome.  Is there a way to do this with Edge?

I managed to get half of the data entered using the AppActivate statement and a series of SendKeys commands - this was with Chrome - but that approach won't work for the rest of it, since AppActivate doesn't seem to really commandeer the browser window in a way that allows Selenium to click buttons etc.

Comment: Maybe look at this https://cosmocode.io/how-to-connect-selenium-to-an-existing-browser-that-was-opened-manually/   Not sure if it works with Selenium basic

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you - I'm able to open an instance of the Chrome browser using the process described on that site, so I'm assuming that I should be able to control it using Selenium in Excel VBA. Unfortunately I'm not sure how to reference an open Chrome browser in the VBA code so I haven't tested it yet, but I will try to figure that out!

Comment: Sorry never done it myself, so can't offer any hints...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use control browser with selenium Basic. You can follow instruction on how to get it working with vba here. [https://simpleexcelvba.com/google-chrome-automation-with-selenium-basic/#:~:text=Selenium%20Basic%20is%20a%20Selenium,by%20double%2Dclicking%20on%20it](https://simpleexcelvba.com/google-chrome-automation-with-selenium-basic/#:%7E:text=Selenium%20Basic%20is%20a%20Selenium,by%20double%2Dclicking%20on%20it).

if you want to login manually and use already open chrome window. You should launch chrome in remote debugging mode after that manually login to your required site after which you can run seleinum script.

Instruction on how to use an already running (Chrome) browser

https://robocorp.com/docs/development-guide/browser/how-to-attach-to-running-chrome-browser

you can turn this command to a batch script for repeatdly use

```
start "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

Comment: Thank you - that link contains some useful information, but unfortunately it does not pertain to my specific question.

Comment: updated answer try now